# Replace NaN values with other values from same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

My DF looks like that

```
id    zip     location
X2    65123   Houston
T5    65123   Houston
A1    nan     Houston
M8    89517   Berkley
X3    89518   Berkley
N2    nan     Berkley
M9    nan     nan
```

For some values in 'zip' I don't have the zipcode, but an entry in 'location'.
I'd like to fill the nan values in 'zip' with one of the zipcodes from the same location. Sometimes there are more than one option, e.g. for N2 there are two options 89517 and 89518, which one to pick doesn't matter that much. But I don't want to change the ones where I have nan's in zip and location. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't care which value to use, we can use the `max` value:

```
>>> df['zip'] = df.groupby('location')['zip'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max())).astype(int)
>>> df

   id    zip location
0  X2  65123  Houston
1  T5  65123  Houston
2  A1  65123  Houston
3  M8  89517  Berkley
4  X3  89518  Berkley
5  N2  89518  Berkley
```

If you need to handle cases where `zip` and `location` are both `NaN`s, first, filter out the subgroup:

```
>>> sub_df = df.loc[df[['zip', 'location']].notna().any(1)]
>>> df
   id      zip location
0  X2  65123.0  Houston
1  T5  65123.0  Houston
2  A1      NaN  Houston
3  M7      NaN      NaN    # <-- added a line in between to show index is maintained
4  M8  89517.0  Berkley
5  X3  89518.0  Berkley
6  N2      NaN  Berkley
7  M9      NaN      NaN

>>> sub_df
   id      zip location
0  X2  65123.0  Houston
1  T5  65123.0  Houston
2  A1      NaN  Houston    # <-- No index 3
4  M8  89517.0  Berkley
5  X3  89518.0  Berkley
6  N2      NaN  Berkley
```

Then perform the same operation (only this time you don't need to cast as `int` since you will have `NaN`s in your frame anyways):

```
df['zip'] = sub_df.groupby('location')['zip'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max()))
```

Result:

```
   id      zip location
0  X2  65123.0  Houston
1  T5  65123.0  Houston
2  A1  65123.0  Houston
3  M7      NaN      NaN
4  M8  89517.0  Berkley
5  X3  89518.0  Berkley
6  N2  89518.0  Berkley
7  M9      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Doesn't work due to observations with nan's in zip and location.

Comment: Added subgroup handling.  Please see updated answer.

Comment: I got "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'". If i convert zip to str before, "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4937 elements, new values have 5113 elements"

Comment: Solved: there was an observation with an x in zip! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about which value to fill in, one simple method is to sort the table by location and zip, then use fillna with method='ffill'

```
 >>> df
       zip location
0  65123.0  Houston
1  65123.0  Houston
2      NaN  Houston
3  89517.0  Berkley
4  89518.0  Berkley
5      NaN  Berkley

>>> df.sort_values(by=['location','zip']).fillna(method='ffill')
       zip location
3  89517.0  Berkley
4  89518.0  Berkley
5  89518.0  Berkley
0  65123.0  Houston
1  65123.0  Houston
2  65123.0  Houston
```

Update: Below solution handles nan in location also. First with groupby function and then fillna by max within the group.

```
>>> df
       zip location
0  65123.0  Houston
1  65123.0  Houston
2      NaN  Houston
3  89517.0  Berkley
4  89518.0  Berkley
5      NaN  Berkley
6      NaN      NaN

>>> df['zip'] = df.groupby('location')['zip'].apply(lambda x:x.fillna(x.max()))
>>> df
       zip location
0  65123.0  Houston
1  65123.0  Houston
2  65123.0  Houston
3  89517.0  Berkley
4  89518.0  Berkley
5  89518.0  Berkley
6      NaN      NaN
```